# Dynamic Lightning Select With Dynamic Amount of Options

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm looking to have a dynamic input that can be either a Dynamic PickList OR A Dynamic Input such as text or DateTime.

```
$A.createComponent(String type, Object attributes, function callback)
```

I have been using the above to great effect with lightning input. However, when I try to do the same with lightning select, all of the guidance says that I can't have a dynamic amount of options as it seems each option has to be hardcoded like below!

```
$A.createComponent(
    "lightning:select", [
        [
            "aura:id": "input",
            "label": cmp.get("v.label"),
            "onchange": cmp.getReference("c.onChange")
        ],
        [
            "option", {
                value: "Option 1",
                label: "Option 1"
            }
        ],
        [
            "option", {
                value: "Option 2",
                label: "Option 2"
            }
        ]
    ],
    function(icmp, status, errorMessage) {
        if (status === "SUCCESS") {
            var body = cmp.get("v.body");
            body.push(icmp);
            cmp.set("v.body", body);
        } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("No response from server or client is offline.")
        } else if (status === "ERROR") {
            console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
        }
    }
);
```

Now I know I can set the value/label of each dynamically, but I cannot seem to have a dynamic number of options matching the length of a list, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I understood you want to bind options to variable, you can do this by using component.setReference. From what I remember it'll work like this `icmp.setReference('v.options', cmp.getReference('v.myDynamicOptions'))`

Comment: This will work for lightning select?
Normally you have to do something like the below if setting static
`<lightning:select name="select1" label="How many tickets?" required="true">

     <option value="">choose one...</option>

     <option value="1">one</option>

     <option value="2">two</option>

     <option value="3">three</option>

</lightning:select>`

Comment: What format would myDynamicOptions need to be in?

Comment: the same way you specified in your parameters array of {label, value}

Comment: ok. mb I forgot that you can't just use attribute for it. Then you need to create a custom component with options attribute which will create this child options for you in <aura:iteration>

Comment: I can't do that though as it could be a lightning:select or a lightning:input radiobutton so I cannot hard code it like that

Comment: I mean to create a custom component like c:mySelect so you can pass options as an attribute and then based on your criteria you can render either c:mySelect of lightning:input

Comment: right make a component that can accept it inline effectivley

Comment: yep like this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example